# Is there a way to get number of measures in a measure group using GetSchemaDataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, ssas, olap

we have a cube browser using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient to get the data.
When we get MeasureGroups, we use
`GetSchemaDataSet("MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS", restrictions)`

We want to hide MeasureGroups without any Measures, but the only way we've found to do this is to do
`GetSchemaDataSet("MDSCHEMA_MEASURES", restrictions)`
for each MeasureGroup, and that takes a long time for our cubes.

Is there a way to get number of Measures already when we get the MeasureGroups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We normal query the [DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions) like below to get the details of measures. i.e., query the `$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES` DMV. This is usually very fast in our environment.

```
SELECT [MEASUREGROUP_NAME], [MEASURE_NAME], * FROM $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
ORDER BY [MEASUREGROUP_NAME]
```

More details in the very old blog:
https://bennyaustin.com/2011/03/01/ssas-dmv-queries-cube-metadata/

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
So I could do a SELECT in an AdomdClient.Execute, instead of a GetSchemaDataSet()?